# php "if" without answer

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

This problem should be simple to resolve, but I can't...
After a request, a condition has to verify if the concerned article really exists, verifying the URL ($_GET).

**My code** : ( a testing file with simple echos )

```
    $id = $bdd->prepare('SELECT content FROM articles WHERE idArticle = ?');
    $id->execute(array($_GET['numArticle']));

    while ($dataID = $id->fetch()) {
        if (empty($dataID) or $dataID == null or !isset($dataID)) {   
           echo 'No content';
        } else {
            echo 'Can load the page';
        }
    }

    $id->closeCursor();
```

**The page behaviour** : "can load the page" is writing when numArticle is right, but if it is not, nothing appears, neither an error message or something.
Any idea/advice? Thank you.

Comment: If `$dataID` is empty - `while` is __false__ and it does not execute.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the 'while' was a requirement for fetch execution...

Comment: If there's __nothing__ to fetch, how can `while` be executed?

Comment: Also, `empty || !isset` is redundant, and since you are setting the variable in the previous line both are superfluous. Just `if ($dataId == null)`, or probably just `if (!$dataID)` will do just fine (if it wasn't  for `while`…).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know how mysql will answer ( empty, null, !isset ) and wanted to be sure to get it to test. I've refined it.

Comment: You can figure that out by consulting [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.fetch-returnvalues) or testing the return value with `var_dump`. Don't just throw code in because "you don't know." Also see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by checking the number of rows returned by mysqli:

```
$id = $bdd->prepare('SELECT content FROM articles WHERE idArticle = ?');
$id->execute(array($_GET['numArticle']));  

if($id->num_rows > 0){
  echo "can load page";
}else{
 echo 'No content';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is more simple. I've to study possibilities of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetchAll()` function of PDO then run a foreach loop on data:

```
$rows = $id->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!empty($rows)){
    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo "content";
    }
}
else{
    echo "No Content";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting. It just SEEMS to work even without the foreach loop in this case. I just wanted to post the cooresponding page ( of $_GET ).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Pdo, it looks like you want to be using Pdo's fetchColumn method.

```
<?php

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT content FROM articles WHERE idArticle = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['numArticle']));

if ($result = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    echo 'A result';
} else {
    echo 'Db fetch returned false (or could be a string that evaluates to false).';
}
```